# https-portalを利用したvue-routerのmode:historyについて

Tags: docker, vue.js, https

vue-routerのmode:historyを用いたwebアプリケーションをdockerを使ってデプロイしています。
その際に、https対応するべく、https-portalを採用し、リリースまでできましたが、F5ボタンを押下した際に、404エラーとなってしまいます。

公式サイトには下記のように記載がありますが、
下記の記載をしてもうまくいきません。

https://router.vuejs.org/ja/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E4%BE%8B

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

今回の構造は、https-portalをリバースプロキシとして採用し、
80ポートを受けるコンテナをhttps-portal、
8080ポートを受けるコンテナをxxxxx.comとして
二つのコンテナを起動し、80ポートを8080ポートに転送する処理を行っています。

https-portalのコンテナにはindex.htmlは無く、
xxxxx.comのwebアプリケーションを実行しているコンテナにindex.htmlが存在します。

```
ファイル名：nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen      80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return      444;
    }
}
```

```
ファイル名：xxxxx.com.conf

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxxxx.com;

    location / {
      return    301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

          location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
          alias /var/www/default/challenges/;
          try_files $uri =404;
      }
}
```

```
ファイル名：xxxxx.com.ssl.conf

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name xxxxx.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/lib/https-portal/xxxxx.com/production/chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/https-portal/xxxxx.com/production/domain.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /var/lib/https-portal/dhparam.pem;
    # Send HSTS header if configured

    # Prevent Nginx from leaking the first TLS config
    if ($host != $server_name) {
        return 444;
    }
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.3:8080;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
}
```

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;をどこかに採用すればよいか、
教えて頂けますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決できたので、記録として残しておきます。

Spring bootとVue routerを利用したF5対策は、
Spring boot側のコントローラーで制御してあげると404にならずに済みます。

```
@GetMapping("/*")
public String indexAll(Principal principal) {
    if (Objects.isNull(principal)) {
        return "redirect:login";
    }
    return "../static/index";
}
```

全て（/*）のgetリクエストに対し、staticフォルダのindex.htmlに返しています。
※ 未ログインの場合は、ログインページに飛ばします。

ただし、このままだとvue.jsが存在しないurlにも画面遷移できてしまうため、
存在しないurlはvue routerにて制御してあげ、適切な404ページを表示してあげましょう。